# What's the difference between Unity3D's Windows Store build and PC Standalone build?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, build, surface

I want to use a Microsoft Surface 4 pro to test my app built with Unity, I can see there are 2 options, either through Windows Store or simply make a PC standalone .exe file and run it on the device.

My question is will it make a difference in terms of how touch inputs or any other aspect of the app are handled?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on requirements.

If your App is traditional window based with title bar etc and it only supports simple mouse events click, double-click, right-click, scroll etc you should go with Stand-alone build. If it contains features of smart app like multi-touch input, pinch etc. go with Windows store App.

NOTE: For Windows Store App there are certain requirements like Windows 10 SDK etc. And there are few things that are not supported. [Read More](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-gettingstarted.html)

You should ask this type of questions on Unity 3D forum, as this is not a programming related question.

Hope this helps